# executable file window closes halfway (python)

Tags: python

So I wrote a really simple code that multiplies two numbers. This code works perfectly fine when I run it from Visual studio but when I build an exe file of it, it just closes after running half of the code. To be specific, the exe window closes right after I enter the 2nd input. Im very new to programming and stuff pls help

```
askuser = str.lower(input("This is a program multiplies numbers! Do you wish to use it? \nY/N\n"))

def lol():
    global x
    x = print("Enter a number :(")
    multiply_code()
def multiply_code():
    num2 = (input("Input your first number : \n "))
    if num2.isalpha():
        lol()
    num1 = (input("Input your second number : \n "))
    if num1.isalpha():
        lol()
    product = float(num1)*float(num2)
    print(product)
def exitcode():
    print("well, noone asked you to use this in the first place >:(")
if askuser == str("y"):
    multiply_code()
    
else:
    exitcode()
```

Comment: I assume you've created a batch file to run the python script. can you share the code within the batch file?

Comment: It is probably running fully but closing the window before you can see the output. Add a line at the end: `input("Hit enter to exit...")`

Comment: within the batch file add `@pause` at the end to keep the window open